# Pass command line parameters to a program inside the shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, arguments

As for `./script.sh arg1 [arg2 arg3 ...]`, the command line arguments `arg1`, `arg2`, ... can be got by `$1`, `$2`, ... But the number of arguments is **NOT** fixed.

In the shell script, I want to pass the arguments starting from `arg2` to a program,

```
#/bin/bash
...
/path/to/a/program [I want to pass arg2 arg3 ... to the program]
...
```

How could I do it since there could be one or more arguments?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The usual way would be to save a copy of *arg1* (`"$1"`) and shift the parameters by one, so you can refer to the whole list as `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/sh
arg1="$1"
shift 1
/path/to/a/program "$@"
```

bash has some array support of course, but it is not needed for the question as posed.

If even *arg1* is optional, you would check for it like this:

```
if [ $# != 0 ]
then
    arg1="$1"
    shift 1
fi
```

Comment: Is the double quotes necessary when using `$@`?

Comment: The double-quotes with `$@` tells the shell to double-quote each parameter (something nice to do if the parameters contain interesting characters such as parentheses or asterisks).  If you don't care about that, a plain `$*` works...

Comment: @Lee Yes, the double quotes are necessary. Otherwise, instead of passing through the list of arguments, each argument is split at whitespace, then each piece is interpreted as a wildcard pattern and, if the pattern matches, it's replaced by the list of matches. Generally, speaking, [always double quote variable substitutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Answer (score 10):

You can slice the positional parameters using parameter expansion. The syntax is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

If `length` is omitted it is taken as till the last value.

As you were to pass from second to last arguments, you need:

```
${@:2}
```

**Example:**

```
$ foo() { echo "${@:2}" ;}

$ foo bar spam egg
spam egg
```