# bash script combining commands enable flags?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, cowsay

I made a basic bash script piping fortune and cowsay to make a wise cow, and titled it appropriately as wisecow
Is there a way I can enable the flags associated with cowsay so that I can input

```
wisecow -s
```

and get the stoner cow, or -b for the borg cow, or what have you?

Currently when I do

```
wisecow -d
```

or whatever, the cow looks the same as if I hadn't used the flag

the code lol:

```
#!/bin/bash
fortune | cowsay
```

Comment: You can use the bash builtin command `getopts` so that your script can process its arguments and you can pass them on to whichever command. Search here and Stack Overflow for getopts, there are loads of examples.

Comment: thank you. would I just put that in a new line on the script?

Comment: Related: [Pass command line parameters to a program inside the shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304895/pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-program-inside-the-shell-script)

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I forgot to put it in when I rewrote the post, I'll pop it in.

That fixed it, thank you very much @steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give some option to your script, but you never pass it on to `cowsay`.

To do that, use

```
fortune | cowsay "$@"
```

in your script.  The `"$@"` will expand to the list of command line arguments that your script was given, for example the option `-d`, if that was what you invoked your script with.